How to prevent two Message consumer (like Azure Service Bus consumer) updating same redis value at the same time
I have two Azure Aervice Bus (ASB) consumer running on two different pod. Both of them consuming from the same queue of ASB and writing to redis. Now there might be a chance that both the ASB consumer are updating the same redis value for a key. Can you let me know how to handle this scenario so that when one pod's consumer instance is updating a redis value then another consumer instance should not be allowed to update it until the first consumer is done. Once first consumer is done then second consumer can go ahead and update the value.
I was seeing some option like locking mechanism using the SET command with the NX and PX options or handling transaction using WATCH and EXEC, though not sure which approach would be more suitable to tackle this scenario or if there is any other effective approach. Now can anyone please let me know how to handle/fix this scenario
I am using redis 7.2.3 azure pass service. And from tech stack standpoint I am using Spring Boot (Spring data redis lettuce library), Java etc. Even if someone has some code sample or links then please share the same

How are you reading the message from ASB? If a message is locked by one consumer, other consumer should not be able to read that message. For this, the message must be fetched in Peek-Lock mode.

Here the messages are basically database changelogs. So 2 consumer can consume 2 different changelogs which belong to same value in redis.

This shouldn't be a problem as Redis is single-threaded. The calls to SET will just queue and run without a problem.
If you have multiple calls that need to happen atomically, this gets tricker and you'll want to use a transaction (i.e. WATCH, MULTI, and EXEC). WATCH initiates an optimistic lock. MULTI starts queueing commands without running them. EXEC then runs the whole shebang.
Here's an example:
redis.cloud> WATCH foo bar baz   # watches the keys for changes
OK
redis.cloud> MULTI               # starts the transaction
OK
redis.cloud(TX)> SET foo 42      # queues commands
QUEUED
redis.cloud(TX)> SET bar 23
QUEUED
redis.cloud(TX)> SET baz 13
QUEUED
redis.cloud> EXEC                # executes the queued commands

If nobody else has made a change while the commands where queued, then you get the results of the queued commands back:
1) OK                            # returns result of all commands
2) OK
3) OK

If another client has modified any of the WATCH'd keys, then the call to EXEC returns an (nil). Try again.
(nil)                            # failed transaction, nil returned

